# Is this function harmonic?

Tags: complex-numbers, harmonic-functions, laplacian

$$u(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

I'm trying to figure out if this function is harmonic. I worked out all the algebra and my conclusion is no because the numerator of the final fraction is $2x^3+2xy^2$ which doesn't cancel to zero. I did this by finding the second derivatives of both $x$ and $y$ and adding them together. Does anyone know if this function is supposed to be harmonic? I don't know the syntax for Wolfram for this. Anyway, below is my final answer:

$$=\frac{2x^3+2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pedantic answer:** no, it's not harmonic at $(0,0)$, since it's not defined there.

**Useful answer:** what about away from $(0,0)$?
$$ \partial_y^2 \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = -2x\partial_y \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = -2x\frac{x^2+y^2-4y(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3} = \frac{8 x y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3}-\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}, $$
and similarly,
$$ \partial_x^2 \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \dotsb = \frac{8 x^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3}-\frac{6 x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}, $$
and adding gives zero.

**Clever answer:** with $z=x+iy$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{x+iy} = \frac{x-iy}{(x+iy)(x-iy)} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, $$
so away from $(0,0)$, your function is the real part of the analytic function $1/z$, and hence is harmonic.

Comment: Well....let's see what my teacher says about the pedantic answer.

Comment: Jk, found my mistake. Thanks!!

Comment: Wait so, the question asks if it is harmonic *in the complex plane*. Would I have to add anything different?

Comment: Hopefully that's referring to the issue at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, although to get technical, the harmonic function is $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0\} \to \mathbb{R}$, so the complex plane is not present in the harmonic discussion. The complex bit enters in the analytic function, which is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C} $.

Comment: Ok I'll use what you wrote to research more. One more quick question: I read somewhere (cannot find the link for the life of me) that a multiple of a harmonic function is still harmonic. Is that accurate? Maybe it wasn't "a multiple of", might have been something like "linear additions to a harmonic function are still harmonic". Do you know what I'm referring to?

Comment: The Laplacian is a linear operator: if $f,g$ are functions and $a,b$ constants, then
$$ \Delta(a f+ b g) = a \Delta f + b \Delta g, $$
which you can check directly. Hence a sum of harmonic functions is harmonic, as is a constant multiple of a harmonic function.

Comment: Ahhhhhh there it is! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram can do this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplacian+calculator&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22LaplacianCalculator%22,+%22scalarfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22x%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D).

Without showing work it's hard to say where your calculation was incorrect. A quick way to see that your function is harmonic is that it is the real part of the holomorphic function (away from $0$) $\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: A humble nod for the Wolfram tip.